# Where would the temp chat record go?

Tags: support, chat, privileges, 404-not-found

Sometimes I would like to browse chat context in questions/answers because it may be useful to clarify the question, but sometimes I can see some chat rooms 'Page not found' already (e.g.: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522105/trigger-the-click-event-on-an-element-if-a-condition-is-true-in-angular-js#comment68286683_40522105)). Is the temp chat record aged away automatically? Or it is just like delete questions that hidden for low reputation users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This room has been [automatically deleted for inactivity](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention), because it has less than 15 messages, and has been inactive for over 7 days. I can still see it, so probably deleted rooms are visible to 10k+ users.